# Skip 1second in play mp3 the first time

Tags: pi-4, audio

I'm using Rasp4 and I'm trying to let rasp speaks using gtts-cli. It works but the first time I play it skips more or less 1 second. I run this command:

gtts-cli -l en 'Good morning my dear friend' |  mpg321 -q -

It works but the first time I run it, it misses the word Good, then if I run it again quickly after finished the first command it includes all the words, and sounds ok. If I wait for a minute and try again I get the same problem. Then I try to create an mp3 from the gtts-cli command with this:

gtts-cli -l en 'Good morning my dear friend' --output test.mp3

Then if I play it with mpg321 I have the same problem, so it's not gtts-cli. I try different players like play from sox but same issue.

Comment: sounds like a "feature" where it includes processing time in time of playback/recording... does using all lowercase or including the first word twice make a difference?

Comment: Hi @Abel, no difference at all unfortunately

Comment: you right I made the right adjustment in the post, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed similar issues since the Pi OS switched to Pulse.

Are you using PulseAudio? If so, try switching off the time-based scheduler by adding the following line to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

You could also use a different sound system altogether (e.g. ALSA or JACK) if your software supports it. ALSA is one level below Pulse, so you should already have it. JACK has to be installed separately.

If that doesn't help, a possible workaround is to play an empty sentence (e.g. " " or ".") before the actual sentence you wanted to play.

Comment: To add a bit: Pulse is mostly about multiplexing -- allowing multiple applications/sources to produce sound at the same time -- which is desirable on a normal desktop, but not necessary if you want to work with only one source at a time.  It does have a reputation for causing problems.

Comment: @goldilocks Exactly. And one of the design goals for Pulse is to avoid noticeable delays or other lasting issues, even if that means to skip a chunk of data in the beginning a stream.

Comment: Hello @DmitryGrigoryev thanks for your answer I'm using both alsa and pulse but i don't know how to check which one has been using when I use mpg321. I try to add what you suggest but unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: @NiBE Have you restarted Pulse after making the changes? `mpg321` uses whatever you tell it to use, e.g. `mpg321 -o alsa` will use ALSA. I'm not sure whether it supports Pulse, look it up in the man page.